# How to efficiently sample uniformly from the set of $p$-equipartitions of an $n$-set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, algorithms, probability-distributions

I have a question related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141999/how-to-efficiently-sample-uniformly-from-the-set-of-p-partitions-of-an-n-set). For $n,p \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that $p\mid n$, let $\mathcal{P}^{\rm eq}$ be the set of all *equipartitions* of $n$ in $p$ sets; i.e., in sets of equal size $\frac{n}{p}$.

> Is it known how to sample efficiently (i.e., in time polynomial in $n,p$) from the uniform distribution on $\mathcal{P}^{\rm eq}$?

**Edit:** I had forgotten a key part: can this be done using the optimal (up to constant factors) number of random bits, i.e., $O(n\log p)$ uniformly random bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randomly permute $n$ and then divide into blocks of size $n/p$.

Comment: OK, that was dumb of me, I forgot the condition on the number of random bits (i.e., using only $O(n \log p)$ uniformly random bits). I know it's frowned upon to so I will ask:  do you mind if I edit my question to add said condition? If you do, I'll accept your answer and ask another one.

Comment: (very neat solution, by the way)

Comment: No worries and thanks.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it addresses my original question.